# Inconsistent behavior of fetch()

Tags: javascript, event-handling, fetch-api

I am working on a emailing app similar to Gmail. In order to load all the emails, I use fetch() and all the emails which are not archived are loaded on the webpage. Similarly, I use fetch() to mark a email as archived/unarchived.

```
 archive.addEventListener('click', e=>{
        if(e.target.innerHTML === "Archive"){
          fetch(`/emails/${element.id}`, {
            method: 'PUT',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                archived: true
            })
          })
        }
        else{
          fetch(`/emails/${element.id}`, {
            method: 'PUT',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                archived: false
            })
          })
        }
        e.stopPropagation();
        load_mailbox('inbox');
});
```

`load_mailbox('inbox')` fetches all the emails in the inbox which are not archived. Whenever archive button is clicked on a email, inbox should be loaded and that particular email should not be visible. But instead I need to click archive button twice for the inbox to load correctly.

To solve this I added a timeout of 1000ms to `load_mailbox('inbox')` and it worked perfectly. Now the inbox would correctly, as in, without the email that was archived.

```
archive.addEventListener('click', e=>{
    if(e.target.innerHTML === "Archive"){
      fetch(`/emails/${element.id}`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            archived: true
        })
      })
    }
    else{
      fetch(`/emails/${element.id}`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            archived: false
        })
      })
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
    if(timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(()=>{load_mailbox('inbox')}, 1000);
  });
```

I cannot understand the reason why it needs a timeout and a cleaner way to solve it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetch` is synchronous - the rest of your code will run while waiting for the http request to complete.  Sounds like you just need to wait for the call to complete, a simple way to do that would be to make your function async, and `await` the fetch call:

```
archive.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  if(e.target.innerHTML === "Archive"){
    await fetch(`/emails/${element.id}`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: JSON.stringify({
          archived: true
      })
    })
  }
  else{
    await fetch(`/emails/${element.id}`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: JSON.stringify({
          archived: false
      })
    })
  }

  load_mailbox('inbox');
});
```